# loading initial data from fixtures.json to django test database with pytest

Tags: django, pytest, python-unittest, fixtures

I work on a legacy code that has some initial data for the `Status` model with predefined `pk` in `status_data.json` that has been loaded with the command `python manage.py load data <fixturename>`.

```json
{
        "model": "status.Status",
        "pk":4,
        "fields": {
            "item": "Achat",
            "table": "billing_models",
            "attribute": "status_billing_models"

          }
}
```

With some models that have foreign key relationship with the `Status` model, the status' pks are `STATIC`:

```python
class BillingModel(Timestemps, SafeDeleteModel):
    ACHAT = 4
    ACTIVATION = 5

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ... more fields here

    # achat or activation
    cycle_start_at = models.ForeignKey(Status, models.CASCADE)
```

Now I want to write some tests for this legacy code, and I wanna know how to load these initial data in `django tests database` with `pytest` so that I can write some tests based on this initial data.